# How do I run a Bash script in an Alpine Docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I have a directory containing only two files, `Dockerfile` and `sayhello.sh`:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
└── sayhello.sh
```

The `Dockerfile` reads

```
FROM alpine
COPY sayhello.sh sayhello.sh
CMD ["sayhello.sh"]
```

and `sayhello.sh` contains simply

```
echo hello
```

The `Dockerfile` builds successfully:

```
kurtpeek@Sophiemaries-MacBook-Pro ~/d/s/trybash> docker build --tag trybash .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.072 kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine
 ---> 665ffb03bfae
Step 2/3 : COPY sayhello.sh sayhello.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fe41f2497715
Step 3/3 : CMD sayhello.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dfcc26c78541
Successfully built dfcc26c78541
```

However, if I try to `run` it I get an `executable file not found in $PATH` error:

```
kurtpeek@Sophiemaries-MacBook-Pro ~/d/s/trybash> docker run trybash
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"sayhello.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH"
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"sayhello.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH".
ERRO[0001] error getting events from daemon: net/http: request canceled
```

What is causing this? I recall running scripts in `debian:jessie`-based images in a similar manner. So perhaps it is Alpine-specific?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Alpine comes with [ash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell) as the default shell instead of `bash`.

So you can

1. Have a shebang defining /bin/bash as the first line of your sayhello.sh, so your file sayhello.sh will begin with bin/sh

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   ```
2. Install Bash in your Alpine image, as you seem to expect Bash is present, with such a line in your Dockerfile:

   ```
   RUN apk add --no-cache --upgrade bash
   ```

Comment: Changing `CMD ["sayhello.sh"]` to `CMD ["./sayhello.sh"]` in Dockerfile solved the problem for me, without the need for installing Bash.

Comment: I needed to add `#!/bin/ash` to the top of the script to have it interpreted correctly

Comment: The point 1. says "Have a shebang defining /bin/bash as the first line of your sayhello.sh," should that be "defining /bin/sh" ?

Answer (score 41):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44804509/1924666) is completely right and works fine.

There is another way. You can run a Bash script in an Alpine-based Docker container.

You need to change CMD like below:

```
CMD ["sh", "sayhello.sh"]
```

And this works too.

Comment: Though this may work bash scripts are not 100% API compatible with sh scripts. sh I believe stands for shell where as Bash stands for Bourne Again SHell. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/What-is-Bash_003f.html#What-is-Bash_003f So just so future visitors know they really are different shells.

Comment: The question is explicitly looking for a way to run "bash", not "sh". Just saying run the bash script using sh is not an answer - it's an anti-answer! What if that script has a command unique to bash?

Answer (score 12):

Remember to grant execution permission for all scripts.

```
FROM alpine
COPY sayhello.sh /sayhello.sh
RUN chmod +x /sayhello.sh
CMD ["/sayhello.sh"]
```

Comment: grant execution permission is not required in Dockerfile if it has permission already

Comment: Excuse my boldness in asking you a question, because when I terminate my Dockerfile that way, and I have run it with `docker-compose up -d`, I can't access the `bash`, while with other containers like `php, nginx` that terminate with `CMD`, I can access the `bash`.

Comment: @jcarlosweb because Alpine ships no bash, only ash

Answer (score 5):

By using the `CMD`, Docker is searching the `sayhello.sh` file in the `PATH`, BUT you copied it in `/` which is not in the `PATH`.

So use an absolute path to the script you want to execute:

```
CMD ["/sayhello.sh"]
```

BTW, as @user2915097 said, be careful that Alpine doesn't have Bash by default in case of your script using it in the shebang.