# Running a bash script from alpine based docker

Tags: bash, docker, alpine-linux

I have Dockerfile containing:

```
FROM alpine

COPY script.sh /script.sh

CMD ["./script.sh"]
```

and a `script.sh` (with executable permission):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello world from script file"
```

when I run

```
docker run --name testing fff0e5c81ca0
```

where fff0e5c81ca0 is the id after building, I get an error

```
standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

So how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you try `CMD ["sh /script.sh"]`?

Comment: I can't make it works `CMD ["sh /script.sh"]`

Comment: In alpine, ENTRYPOINT is already `/bin/sh`.

Comment: I got it. Do you want to add answer? Or I will update my answer @Maroun

Comment: I got this ... docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "exec: \"sh /script.sh\": stat sh /script.sh: no such file or directory": unknown.
ERRO[0002] error waiting for container: context canceled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a bash script in an Alpine Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803982/how-to-run-a-bash-script-in-an-alpine-docker-container)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To run a bash script in alpine based image, you need to do either one

1. Install bash

   ```
   $ RUN apk add --update bash
   ```
2. Use `#!/bin/sh` in script instead of `#!/bin/bash`

You need to do any one of these two or both

Or, like @Maroun's answer in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48597225/running-a-bash-script-from-alpine-based-docker/48597398?noredirect=1#comment84191110_48597225), you can change your CMD to execute your bash script

```
CMD ["sh", "./script.sh"]
```

Comment: Or change to  `CMD ["sh /script.sh"]`.

Comment: I think CMD requires an array.

Comment: yes, you can provide multiple args to ENTRYPOINT using  CMD with array. Thanks to @Maroun

Comment: please, delete your last comment `upvoted`. You can be flagged. Its agains roles. @Mumbaikar007

Comment: You can use Bash to run `sh` scripts but not vice versa. The OP's current script is `sh` compatible but you really should at least mention that there is a difference. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash

Answer (score 1):

Your Dockerfile may look like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8u171-jre-alpine3.8
COPY script.sh /script.sh
CMD ["sh", "./script.sh"]
```

Comment: FROM alpine:3.6
RUN apk --no-cache add curl bash
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
RUN apk add --update bash
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/cron \
    && touch /var/log/cron/cron.log \
    && mkdir -m 0644 -p /etc/cron.d
COPY run.sh /usr/share/run.sh
ADD curlurl /etc/crontabs/sit/
ADD curlurl2 /etc/crontabs/uat/
RUN chmod +x /usr/share/run.sh
CMD bash -c "crond -L /var/log/cron/cron.log && tail -F /var/log/cron/cron.log"
WORKDIR /usr/share/
#CMD ["sh", "./run.sh"]
in run.sh (#!/bin/bash
cp -f /etc/crontabs/sit/curlurl /etc/crontabs/root) but getting error as file not found.