# Running script in docker container

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I try to set up two dockers. One with service and one with a database. On my docker with service, I try to run script wait-for-it.sh from https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it.

I tried to do all this stuff using a docker-compose file, but I isolate my problem to running .sh file at the start of a container.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
COPY ./target/docker-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  /app.jar
COPY ./src/main/resources/wait-for-it.sh  /wait-for-it.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/wait-for-it.sh", "192.168.99.100:5432", "--", "java", "-jar", 
"/app.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

I was using clean ash from the alpine image, Next, I was installing bash. Of course, i was changing the first line of code of script from

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

into

```
#!/bin/sh
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Nothing help. I saw this topic [How to run a bash script in an Alpine Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803982/how-to-run-a-bash-script-in-an-alpine-docker-container) but it did not help either.

I always receive "no such file or directory". I was messing with

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/wait-for-it.sh"...
```

by adding "." or "./"

The entire project I am building on windows with docker tool for windows 8. Maybe there is a reason?

Comment: Can you add `RUN ls -la /` after `COPY wait-for-it.sh`. And see what happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. Two days I spent figuring out why it's not working. My host machine is windows, so the wait-for-it.sh file was formatted for dos.

1. I had to run `dos2unix wait-for-it.sh` command to convert the file for unix systems. ([Convert files to unix systems](http://bencane.com/2014/02/11/converting-files-from-windows-format-to-unix-format-with-dos2unix/))
2. I added in the Dockerfile these 3 lines:

`RUN apk add --no-cache bash

COPY wait-for-it.sh /wait-for-it.sh

RUN chmod +x /wait-for-it.sh`

Afterwards the wait-for-it.sh ran when the container was starting.

If you are using GIT, git handles line endings depending by host machine.
You have to add a file `.gitattributes` inside your project and add into this file this line `*.sh eol=lf`.
So you are telling that all your .sh files to have the line endings in LF

Comment: Great answer. I am sorry I can't upvote you. One thing. Did you install dos2unix on docker? Or you just did it manually in your environment?

Comment: I didn't install dos2unix on docker, I've did it manually on my host machine

Answer (score 0):

```
COPY ./src/main/resources/wait-for-it.sh  /wait-for-it.sh
```

This line is the culprit. Use this if the script is in absolute directory

```
COPY /src/main/resources/wait-for-it.sh  /wait-for-it.sh
```

or use this if the script is in relative directory

```
COPY src/main/resources/wait-for-it.sh  /wait-for-it.sh
```

and then run this

```
RUN chmod 700 /wait-for-it.sh
```

Comment: Vamsi, thanks for answer. My COPY comand with script works fine. I see script in the same place where my jar inside docker is. So this should not be a problem.

Comment: Did you try setting the permissions like mentioned in the last step.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the copy statement try giving the target folder only.

   e.g. 
   COPY ./src/main/resources/wait-for-it.sh /app
2. Also set the working directory where the container starts

   WORKDIR /app

Also ensure that you have given execute permissions to the file like @vamsi suggested in his answer.